# error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to WebElement for findbyclassname

Tags: android, appium

Wanted to write a common function for handling pop up message in Android:

```
public static WebElement andDismiss() {
        for(WebElement e : appiumDriver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button")) {
            if(e.getAttribute("text").equals("No") || e.getAttribute("text").equals("Cancel")) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to WebElement